# How to coloring the bottom area of kendo scatterline chart?

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, scatter-plot, kendo-chart, area-chart

I want to color the bottom area of kendo scatterLine chart.

But when i use x,y Axis for scatterLine chart, it is impossible to coloring the bottom area.

Is there any way to coloring the bottom area of kendo scatterLine chart?

Please help me..

I tried to coloring the area using svg, but it's pretty hard to managing the coordinate of scatterLine chart's points.

And it is not possible to create scatterLine & Area chart both at one chart Area.

Comment: Have you tried the drawing api? Is this kendo example kind of what you are looking for https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/draw-on-scatter-plots ?